# Symfony 5 generate authentication for multi users types

Tags: symfony, authentication

I'm working on a symfony 5 project .

I need to create multi user types : an organizer and a participant …

And i want to generate authentication for those users

I generated a user : `php bin/console make:user`

And then :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "organizer" = "Organizer",
 *     "participant" = "Participant",
 * })
 */
class User implements UserInterface
```

I created an Organizer entity  : `class Organizer  extends User`

I added a Participant entity :  `class Participant  extends User`

I will be thankful if someone explain how can i generate an authentication for those users Organizer and Participant  using  `php bin/console make:auth`

Comment: Not really sure what you need explained.  Both of your user classes derive from User so a single auth class can handle both.  If you really need two completely different authentication setups then run make:auth twice and customize accordingly.

Comment: I was asking, if i should create an authentication related to User entity or i should create different authentication for  Organizer and Participant ? but finally you're right.

Comment: What you should really be asking is if you really need two different user types at all.  Have a ROLE_ORGANIZER and ROLE_PARTICIPANT might be all you need.

Comment: i tried to use roles but it doesn't enough for me coz each entity has a unique process and unique forms … even in the backend organizer and participant are not managed the some way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once did this where i had two user types as author and admin. Very briefly the admin had his/her own dashboard and the author too, with different entity. I used `make:entity` to make `user` and `author` entity and made sure their content were similar (but you can add to match your app needs). After generating the admin user via `php bin/console make:user`, i had to copy the `user templates, controller e.t.c` php files content and create `author templates, controller e.t.c` with its content, them make migrations/schema update. This is manual and i welcome automated/script generated solution.

#### admin entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="There is already an account with this email")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private ?string $email;
}
```

#### author entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AuthorsRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="authors")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="There is already an Author account with this email")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class AllAuthors implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private ?int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private ?string $email;
}
```

For this to work you need to configure Multiple User Provider and Multiple Guard Authenticators (Separate or Shared Entry Point). You can learn this from [symfony docs here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/multiple_guard_authenticators.html).

Also read this article it may help [Multiple authentication in Symfony 5 with LDAP and DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63194163/multiple-authentication-in-symfony-5-with-ldap-and-db)

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer, but in my case one authenticator work for me , i'm able to create new Organizer and a new Participant and i can login normally

Comment: If both entities are very similar, you might want to consider using a `@ORM\MappedSuperclass` to avoid repetition. Then make both your entities extend your SuperClass. Also if you are copying the same content to controllers, templates, etc, to something almost identical, you might want to consider refactoring to make it DRY.